# R unable to find repository for package RODBC when deploying

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When I deploy to shinyapps.io, it gives me an error:

> Unable to find repository URL for package RODBC

So when I go to open the chart via URL, it doesn't show anything, because it was unable to connect to the connection I had and load the data into the data frames I had created.

Deploy information:

[image]

The package is installed and works normally, even I search the data in my database through it.

Comment: This may be better suited for the RStudio Community site.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the tip, I just signed up on the RStudio Community and I'll post the error there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question in the R ([R Community Question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-find-repository-for-package-rodbc-when-deploying/70827/3)) community, I ended up following the steps as directed by @nirgrahamuk, and the error no longer appears!

So I had to update the R version to the latest one, and it worked!

After having executed the commands in R he asked:

```
> getOption("repos")
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1   rsconnect_0.8.16 tools_3.6.1      curl_4.3         jsonlite_1.6.1  
[6] digest_0.6.25    openssl_1.4.1    askpass_1.1
```

After updating the R version:

```
> getOption("repos")
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.4  lubridate_1.7.9 dplyr_1.0.0     DBI_1.1.0       RODBC_1.3-17    timevis_0.5    
[7] shiny_1.5.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      compiler_4.0.2    pillar_1.4.4      later_1.1.0.1     plyr_1.8.6       
 [6] tools_4.0.2       digest_0.6.25     evaluate_0.14     jsonlite_1.6.1    lifecycle_0.2.0  
[11] tibble_3.0.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.6       cli_2.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11  
[16] yaml_2.2.1        curl_4.3          xfun_0.15         fastmap_1.0.1     withr_2.2.0      
[21] knitr_1.29        stringr_1.4.0     htmlwidgets_1.5.1 generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.1      
[26] askpass_1.1       tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.1        R6_2.4.1          fansi_0.4.1      
[31] rmarkdown_2.3     purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_1.5      promises_1.1.1    htmltools_0.5.0  
[36] ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1  rsconnect_0.8.16  mime_0.9          xtable_1.8-4     
[41] httpuv_1.5.4      stringi_1.4.6     openssl_1.4.1     crayon_1.3.4
```

So the version has been updated from `R version 3.6.1 (2019-7-05)` to `R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)`.

And the error no longer appears:

[image: R Deploy without error]